# Spark: How to prevent DataFrameWriter from dropping the partitioning columns on call to write.partitionBy?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

we are using below method to save a spark sql dataframe

```
public DataFrameWriter<T> partitionBy(scala.collection.Seq<String> colNames)
```

from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#partitionBy(scala.collection.Seq)):

> Partitions the output by the given columns on the file system. If
>   specified, the output is laid out on the file system similar to Hive's
>   partitioning scheme. As an example, when we partition a dataset by
>   year and then month, the directory layout would look like:
>   - year=2016/month=01/
>   - year=2016/month=02/

our code looks like this:

```
df.repartition(new Column("day")).write.partitionBy("day").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(outputPath)
```

we get the directory layout we expect, but we find the parquet files don't have the `day` column in them anymore. we would like the parquet files to have the day column. how can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution is to add a duplicate day column to the dataframe which would get dropped in the parquet file but the original `day` column will still be there.

Comment: Meaning 2 columns with the same name? Is it possible to write such a dataframe in json?

Answer (score 3):

In general, Morpheus's answer is a fine cludge. BUT...

If you are strictly reading and writing in spark, you can just use the basePath option when reading your data.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery

> By passing path/to/table to either SparkSession.read.parquet or SparkSession.read.load, Spark SQL will automatically extract the partitioning information from the paths.

Example:

```
     val dataset = spark
      .read
      .format("parquet")
      .option("basePath", hdfsInputBasePath)
      .load(hdfsInputPath)
```